# How do I read the pictures in the file in order?

Tags: python, image, readfile

I want to read the pictures in a file in the order they are in the file. But when I read it with python it reads mixed. I don't want it sorted. How can I fix this?

```py
def read_img(path):
    
    st = os.path.join(path, "*.JPG")
    
    st_ = os.path.join(path, "*.jpg")
     
    for filename in glob.glob(st):
        print(st)
        #print("filename-------",filename)
        
        img_array_input.append(filename)
        print("image array append : ", filename)
        
    for filename in glob.glob(st_):
        
        img_array_input.append(filename)
        #print("filename-------",filename)
        global size
        size = len(img_array_input)
        
    for i in img_array_input:   

        print("detection ")     
        
        detection(i)
        print("detection out")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyths.png)

original file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1fK8.png)

the order of reading

I want it to read in the order in the original file.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you want to populate the list based on the order in which the files exist in your directory? If so, you need to bear in mind that the order may not be as it would appear if you use, for example, *ls* to examine the directory

Comment: Hi,
normally it is much easier to help if the code and output in the question as text. That makes it much easier to debug. If that isn't feasable it helps to add an image description.

Comment: @NameVergessen Links to images are frowned upon

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of ... when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). [Why not upload images of code on SO  ...?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).  [You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755).

Comment: @Cobra completely agree with you about images. Hence, only "if text is not feasible".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the list populated in the order that *os.listdir()* reveals files then:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import join, splitext

BASE = '.' # directory to be parsed
EXTS = {'jpg', 'JPG', 'jpeg', 'JPEG'} # file extensions of interest

def ext(p):
    _, ext = splitext(p)
    if ext:
        return ext[1:]

def getfiles(base, include_base=True):
    for entry in listdir(base):
        if ext(entry) in EXTS:
            yield join(base, entry) if include_base else entry

detection = [file for file in getfiles(BASE, include_base=False)]

print(detection)
```

**Note:**

*os.listdir()* returns a list of files in arbitrary order